# Python util module call set up first

Tags: python

I have a `util.py` file that has a bunch of methods used by other modules. The `util` module relies on a `setup()` function being called before any other functions can be called. Is there anyway to have this function be called before other functions are called? The functions will be called by other modules as `util.some_func(**args)`.

Comment: Does the `setup` function require any arguments?

Comment: @ShadowRanger no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a module is imported, all code at the "top" level (or the outermost indent level) is executed.  This includes function definitions, class definitions, variables, and function calls.

So, at the bottom of your `util.py` file, just call the function:

```
setup()
```

All code which imports your module will execute the function automatically.

You'll probably want to put in safeguards to avoid performing the setup twice.

Comment: So that's just run upon import, right? It won't be run each time a function is called.

Comment: @NishantRoy: As long as it's at the top level (not inside another function, usually at the bottom of the module so everything is defined before you call it), yeah, only on import. And only the first time the module is imported by anyone; `import` caches modules on  first load, so subsequent `import`s for the same module just load the cached module, they don't actually reimport it. It would be rerun if you call `reload(modulename)` though.